# Return time of the Web API to query oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We created the WebAPI for querying an database. The query returns results that are very huge. We cannot go for pagination as the client application requires the entire result in one call. There was an issue when there is a huge amount of data it throws Out of memory exception. As suggested in other forums I tried to add below tags in the web.config

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
```

(this was placed inside

```
  <system.webServer><security><requestFiltering>
```

and

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
```

Placed inside

```
 <system.web>
```

But after adding, tried calling the API it keeps loading forever(waited for almost 1hour) no data has been returned yet or not threw any error. Is there any possibility of improving the return time inspire the data being huge. Below is the code we are using

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
 {
  string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
  using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY where STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN(" + srtcon + ")";
using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn))
{
    using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand))
    {
        DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(selectResults);
        var returnObject = new { data = selectResults };
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
        {
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
        }
        return response;
```

Comment: One small suggestion would be to call the compiled stored procedure instead of having a hard-coded sql call to the database. This may improve the performance a bit.

Comment: Also if the result set is read only, then I suggest using the DataReader instead of the DataTable. DataReader is faster than the DataTable

Comment: Stored procedure is not possible as we are querying the database that we don't own, where we just have a read only access

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint or logging inside of the Web API method to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Also, approximately how many IDs are in your array? Do you have to have a single SELECT statement to pull all of them at once or can you "break up" the query into several smaller ones? (My first inclination here is to try to "break up" the work as much as possible). Along the same lines, why does the client require this to happen in a single call?

Comment: Currently I am trying to use Two IDs in the array. When I tried giving one Id and it returns the result ( no.of rows was around 45,000)

Comment: Depending on the number of records and number of columns, your application will throw Out of Memory exception. ***There is nothing you can do about it***, unless you send by small chunks.

Comment: @EJoshuaS how would I be logging inside the Web API. I tried inserting break points in the using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn)) & adapter.Fill(selectResults); & adapter.Fill(selectResults); and I was able continue and when I hit continue in the adapter fill statement it started loading. This is my first .net application, and new to these concepts. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Win how would we go the small chunks. Do we need to keep calling the API again and again. How would we know that entire data is returned I mean how many times to call the API. This is my first .NET application

Comment: Well, let client to send an array of 500 Id instead of 45,000.

Comment: I am having issue even if I am giving one I'd as http://localhost:80/API/ProDataConnection?id='TM001'  which has to return 633060 rows

Comment: What's the number of rows when you send both IDs?

Comment: It is 905076 for both the IDs

Comment: There could be a few culprits here: the query itself, filling the Data Table, constructing the response, or actually sending the response. Have you tried putting a stopwatch on the various components and logging the results to see where your holdup is?

Comment: How do we log in the Web API

Comment: As far as I tried debugging with the Breakpoints I see the adapter.Fill(selectReaults) takes the loading for ever.